# What is the difference between Aspects in Java and Macros

Tags: java, macros, aspect

I started to be interested in `Aspects` in Java, however I am having difficulties for understanding the benefits and usage of `Aspects`. I have used `Macros` in C++ before. I suppose `Aspects` are working in a similar way. I mean "Whenever you see X, insert the code Y". Maybe I shouldn't try to use my `Macro` knowledge to learn `Aspects`.

Could you give me some concrete examples that compares `Aspects` and `Macros` to understand this better?

Answer (score 1):

Macros are static code injected then compiled as a whole, where as an Aspect can be both static and dynamic, you add point cuts in your code where the code will be injected, more over aspect add logic to your method, decide whether to proceed or not. for example it is used in logging, security, transaction management...

Answer (score 0):

With Macros you have to indicate in the source code every spot where you want the macro to be applied.

With Aspects you define in a separate place all places that should be changed.

So if you want to add/remove an aspect, you just need to change on spot, but if you want to add/remove a macro, you have to change every location where the macro is used.

On the other hand macros are more powerful, and can be used more freely.